# .net core / standard csproj how to trigger build when external file dependency changes

Tags: csproj

Trying to trigger a build of a .net standard/core csproj when an external file changes.  The file is in the the $(USERPROFILE)\Documents directory.

Have tried Targets with BeforeTargets equal to PrepareForBuild, PreBuildEvent but none work.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" Project="Sdk.props">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net471</TargetFrameworks>
    </PropertyGroup>


    <Target Name="PrepareForBuild2" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
        <Exec Command="echo PrepareForBuild2" />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution - use UpToDateCheckInput

```
<ItemGroup>
    <UpToDateCheckInput Include="$(USERPROFILE)\Documents\MyFile.txt" />
</ItemGroup>
```